# BeforeEach, Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What´s wrong with this code?, it provoke two errors:

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined.

I think is because the chaining .then in BeforeEach, but I can't solve it, can somebody help?. Thanks.

```
const expect = require('expect');
const request = require('supertest');
const{ObjectID} = require('mongodb');

const {app} = require('./../server');
const {Todo} = require('./../models/todo');

if(!module.parent) {
app.listen();
}

const todos=[{
  _id:new ObjectID(),
  text:"2 test todo"
},
{
_id:new ObjectID(),
text:"1 test todo"
}];

beforeEach((done) => {
  Todo.remove({}).then(() => {
    return Todo.insertMany(todos);
  }).then(() => done());
});

describe('DELETE /todos/:id', () => {
  it('most delete a doc', (done) => {
    let hexId = todos[1]._id.toHexString();

    request(app)
    .delete(`/todos/${hexId}`)
    .expect(200)
    .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.body.todo._id).toBe(hexId);
    })
    .end((err, res) => {
        if(err) return done(err);

    Todo.findById(hexId).then((todo) => {
        expect(todo).toNotExist();
        done();
    }).catch((e) => done(e));

    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

-> because callback (done) already called

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined.

although i don't know typeError line number but aspect comment is in below code

```
beforeEach((done) => {
  Todo.remove({}).then(() => {
    return Todo.insertMany(todos);
  })
  .then(() =>{
    describe('DELETE /todos/:id', () => {
      it('most delete a doc', (done) => {
        let hexId = todos[1]._id.toHexString();

        request(app)
        .delete(`/todos/${hexId}`)
        .expect(200)
        .expect((res) => {
                // make sure you are you getting from req.body
            expect(res.body.todo._id).toBe(hexId);
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
            if(err) return done(err);

        Todo.findById(hexId).then((todo) => {
            expect(todo).toNotExist();
            done();
        }).catch((e) => done(e));

        });
      });
    });

});
```